# Separate yaxis from xaxis

Tags: gnuplot

I'm doing a 2D plot. I would need to separate x-axis from y-axis, that is I don't want them to intersect. In practice I need to insert space between the y-axis and my plot, and do the same for the x-axis. What do I have to do?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: The only automated way is to use `set xtics rangelimited`, which restricts the xaxis to the actual data range, see the second example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.1/ellipse.html for an example

Answer (score 0):

Fix both axis ranges, give the `rangelimited` option, and add two out-of range or invalid points to your plot wich have the x- values you want to be the limit.

```
set border 1 + 2 # +4+8 only bottom and left axis/border
set xr [0:5]; set yr [0:6]
set xtics rangelimited nomirr
plot "-","-"
#your dataset
2 3
2.5 4
3.1 2
e
# to limit the range
1 NaN
4 NaN
e
```

The trick with the invalid points seems to only work on the x-axis, so you cannot limit both axes this way.

To limit both axes, you could add a plot with pointsize zero or in the background color.

```
set border 1 + 2 # +4+8 only bottom and left axis/border
set xr [0:5]; set yr [0:5]
set xtics rangelimited nomirr; set ytics rangelimited nomirr
plot "-","-" ps 0
#your dataset
2 3
3 2
e
# to limit the range
0.5 1
4 4.5
e
```